# Check for decimal point and add it at the end if its not there using awk/perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk

I have test.dat file with values given below:

```
    20150202,abc,,,,3625.300000,,,,,-5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    20150202,def,,,,32.585,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    20150202,xyz,,,,12,,,,,0.004167,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

My expected output is shown below:

```
   20150202,abc,,,,3625.300000,,,,,-5.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                     ^. added here
   20150202,def,,,,32.585,,,,,0.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                               ^. added here
   20150202,xyz,,,,12.,,,,,0.004167,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                     ^. added here
```

So if column 6 and 11 doesn't have decimal point in it, then we should add '.' at the end of the file.

I have tried below code but it's throwing error message during split

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $filename = 'test.dat';
    open my $fh, $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
    my @cols_to_change = qw ( 6 11 );
    while (my $val = <$fh>) {
       my @row = split (/,/);
       foreach my $col ( @cols_to_change ) {
          unless ( $row[$col] =~ m/\./ ) { $row[$col] .= '.' }
       }
    print join ( ',', @row );
    }
```

The error message I have received is given below:

```
Use of uninitialized value in split at test.pl line 11, <$fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at test.pl line 13, <$fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at test.pl line 13, <$fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at test.pl line 15, <$fh> line 1.
....
```

I am not allowed to any additional perl modules such as Text::CSV. Also any solution with awk would be of great help!

Comment: Follows on from:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847880/how-to-check-whether-number-has-decimal-point-in-it-and-add-decimal-point-at-the/30848190#30848190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk

Just sub for those fields

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{sub(/^[^\.]+$/,"&.",$6);sub(/^[^\.]+$/,"&.",$11)}1' file
```

or sed

```
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{5\}[^.,]\+\),/\1./;s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^.,]\+\),/\1./' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your error:

```
while (my $val = <$fh>) {
```

Change that to:

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
```

or tell `split` to use `$val`.

```
split ( /,/, $val );
```

In the code above - you're setting `$val` in the while loop, but the various pattern matches and splits *aren't using* `$val` at all.

Also note - the first element in a perl array is `0`. So you should probably have kept the 5 and 10 from the sample code you copied.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847880/how-to-check-whether-number-has-decimal-point-in-it-and-add-decimal-point-at-the/30848190#30848190

This:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = 'test.dat';
open my $fh, $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
my @cols_to_change = qw ( 5 10 );
while (<$fh>) {
    my @row = split(/,/);
    foreach my $col (@cols_to_change) {
        unless ( $row[$col] =~ m/\./ ) { $row[$col] .= '.' }
    }
    print join( ',', @row );
}
```

Outputs:

```
20150202,abc,,,,3625.300000,,,,,-5.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20150202,def,,,,32.585,,,,,0.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
20150202,xyz,,,,12.,,,,,0.004167
```

As requested, when fed your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness,

1. bash

   ```
   (
       IFS=,
       while read -ra f; do 
           for i in 5 10; do 
               [[ ${f[i]} == *.* ]] || f[i]+=.   # add a dot if not there
           done
           echo "${f[*]}"                        # quotes required here
       done < file
   )
   ```

   The parentheses put the code in a subshell so the value of IFS is not changed in your current shell.
2. sed

   ```
   sed -r '
       s/^(([^,]*,){5})([^.,]+),/\1\3.,/
       s/^(([^,]*,){10})([^.,]+),/\1\3.,/
   ' file
   ```